# Fake Ajax request

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jasmine

In order to check the submission of an ajax request, when a user submit a form, I implemented the following test using jasmine (1).

The test is successfully passed but looking at javascript console I get the following error `500 (Internal Server Error)`.

Since I don't care the server response, my questions are:
1) Should I or should I not care about this error.
2) Will it be better to fake the ajax request to avoid `Internal Server Error`? if yes, how in my context?

---

(1)

```
define([
    'backendController'
], function (backendController) {
    // some code
    describe('When button handler fired', function () {
        beforeEach(function () {
            spyOn(backendController, 'submitRequest1').andCallThrough();
            this.view = new MyView({
                el: $('<div><form><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form></div>')
            });
            this.view.$el.find('form').submit();
        });
        it('backendController.submitRequest1 should be called', function () {
            expect(backendController.submitRequest1).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
});
```

---

(2)

```
// backendController object
return {
    submitRequest1: function (message) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: 'someUrl',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                message: message
            }
        }).done(function () {
            // some code
        });
    }
}
```

---

(3)

```
// submitForm in MyView
submitForm: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var formElement =  event.currentTarget;

    if (formElement.checkValidity && !formElement.checkValidity()) {
        this.onError();
    } else {
        backendController. submitRequest1('some data').done(this.onSuccess).fail(this.onError);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test says *"backendController.submitRequest1 should be called"* so you only care about the method to be called. So, just don't `andCallThrough()` and you'll be free of troubles.

#### Update

Maybe you have to `preventDefault()` in the *submit event* so:

```
spyOn(backendController, 'submitRequest1').andCallFake(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

#### Update 2

After checking the rest of your code you have added to the question I still suggest to stop your code execution as sooner as possible. Just until the test in arriving, and this is still until `backendController.submitRequest1()` is called.

In this case is not enough with a simple *mock* in the method due the *return* of this method is used subsequently and your *mock* should respect this:

```
// code no tested
var fakeFunction = function(){
  this.done = function(){ return this };
  this.fail = function(){ return this };
  return this;
}

spyOn(backendController, 'submitRequest1').andCallFake( fakeFunction );
```

When things start to be so complicate to test is a symptom that maybe they can be organized better.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Actually 1) if I make just `spyOn(backendController, 'submitRequest1');` on `this.view.$el.find('form').submit();` I get `Cannot call method 'done' of undefined`. 2) If I make `spyOn(backendController, 'submitRequest1').andCall(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });` I get `has no method 'andCall'`. Anyway I added code to my question to make things more clear.

Comment: I accepted your answer but actually I am not fully satisfied. So I opened another question [How to use jquery deferred object in this context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073622/how-to-use-jquery-deferred-object-in-this-context).