# How to use jQuery deferred object in this context

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jasmine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to test the done and fail Deferred Object by using jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080087/how-to-test-the-done-and-fail-deferred-object-by-using-jasmine)

This question is related to my previous question [Fake Ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070152/fake-ajax-request).

Instead of using the code (1)
I would like to return a `jQuery deferred object`, and then either resolve it or reject it (2 tests needed) to test the expectation when the server accepts it and when the server rejects it.

Any ideas how to accomplish in a good way this task by using jQuery?

(1)

```
describe('When Submit button handler fired', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        var fakeFunction = function () {
            this.done = function () {return this; };
            this.fail = function () {return this; };
            return this;
        };
        spyOn(backendController, 'submitRequest1').andCallFake(fakeFunction);
        this.view = new MyView({
            el: $('<div><form><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form></div>')
        });
        this.view.$el.find('form').submit();
    });
    it('backendController.submitRequest1 should be called', function () {
        expect(backendController.submitRequest1).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Comment: dont want to offend you, but - how is this question different from your previous question and why you cant simply edit that one ?