# Mock the calls to the server by using jasmine

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jasmine

I would like to mock the ajax calls to the server by using jasmine and also test the ***done and fail Deferred Object***.

Currently, I am doing them for real, thus trying to send a bunch of call to the server.

How should I fix the following code to

```
mySpy = spyOn(backendController, 'submitForm').andCallThrough(); 
// it makes a real call to the server

mySpy = spyOn(backendController, 'submitForm'); 
// it does not make a real call to the server but I get the following error
// Cannot call method 'done' of undefined
```

Here is the code about the doSubmitForm

```
doSubmitForm: function (backendController) {
  backendController.submitForm(message.val())
        .done(this.onSuccess)
        .fail(this.onError);
});
```

Comment: In order for this to work, your 'submitForm' needs to return a jQuery deferred object (such as jqXHR etc) ?

Comment: @Karthik I suppose yes, any ideas how to make it?

Comment: you could probably use the 'andCallFake' and make it return a jquery-deferred object. Posting it as an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the failing case, I think the problem is due to the call not returning a jQuery-Deferred object.

To validate this theory, you could probably try something like this:

```
var tmpDefObj = $.Deferred();

spyOn(backendController, 'submitForm').andCallFake(function() {return tmpDefObj;});
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. it works.. by the way actually I have another problem related to this. [How to test the done and fail Deferred Object by using jasmine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080087/how-to-test-the-done-and-fail-deferred-object-by-using-jasmine). Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: sure. i will take a look at your other question later today.